# Redirect only the root of the top domain in a wildcard server block

Tags: nginx

I have a Nginx instance running, serving multiples sites under a common domain: `cloud.example.org`. For example, I serve `website.cloud.example.org` and `admin.cloud.example.org`.

I want to redirect `cloud.example.org` to `website.cloud.example.org`. But *only* the root `/`; So :

- `cloud.example.org` --> redirect to `website.cloud.example.org`
- `cloud.example.org/any_kind_of_file_or_route` --> not redirected

My configuration is as follows (*I omit some irrelevant parts, like ssl*):

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        server_name .cloud.example.org;

        location = / {
            if ($http_host = cloud.example.org) {
                return 301 https://website.cloud.example.org;
            }
            proxy_pass         http://my-upstream-server;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://my-upstream-server;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        }
    }
```

This configuration achieves exactly what I want, but having twice the same `proxy` block seems to me quite a hack. Is there a better way to do it ?

And moreover, I use a `if`, and I know it's not ideal (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), so I would really like to find another solution if possible

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the `if` statement by using two `server` blocks. And to avoid duplicating code, use the `include` directive and place the common lines of code into a separate file.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name cloud.example.org;
    location = / {
        return 301 https://website.cloud.example.org;
    }
    include /path/to/common.conf;
}
server {
    server_name .cloud.example.org;
    include /path/to/common.conf;
}
```

And in the `common.conf` file:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://my-upstream-server;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

Comment: I though I could avoid two servers block but well, this seems to be the cleaner solution so far